# Recursive dynamic query slow in postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, recursion, plpgsql

When I run the recursive query as a straight query against the database it takes only seconds but when I use it in function query takes minutes.
What could be the reason

Here is the query and the function.

```
CREATE or REPLACE function myfunc(table_src text)                      
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE 
myparam integer;
src_rec record;    
BEGIN 

CREATE TABLE mytable as 
SELECT oid,column1, column2 from city_n;
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN moid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;

CREATE INDEX idx_all_oid ON mytable(oid);
CREATE INDEX idx_id_start ON mytable(column1);
CREATE INDEX idx_id_end ON mytable(column2);

CREATE TABLE targettable (
oid INTEGER,    
columnx INTEGER,
columny INTEGER
);

ALTER TABLE targettable ADD COLUMN moid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;

FOR src_rec in EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' ||  quote_ident(table_src) 
LOOP 
myparam:= src_rec.oid;                  

EXECUTE format('        
WITH RECURSIVE myrec(oid, line) AS (  
SELECT oid,UNNEST(ARRAY[column1, column2]) as a ,1 as abc
FROM mytable 
WHERE oid = %s
UNION  
SELECT e.oid,CASE WHEN n.line = e.column2 THEN e.column1 ELSE e.column2 
END, n.line
FROM myrec AS n
INNER JOIN mytable e ON n.line = e.column1  or n.line =  e.column2                              
WHERE %s
)    
INSERT INTO targettable 
select oid,(ARRAY_AGG(abc))[1] columnx,
(ARRAY_AGG(abc))[2] columny from myrec group by oid',myparam,myquery);

END LOOP;  
END;
$$
```

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL anyway? You have no dynamic identifiers.

Comment: I need to run it in a loop in a function.  What I am missing?

Comment: You can just run the statement there is no need for dynamic SQL But you will need to **[edit]** your question and add the complete code of the function

Comment: Thanks for your comment, there is no change in time when I don't use dynamic sql. It takes same time when I use straight query. I think I need to add the complete function

Comment: I added the function

Comment: What are the (supposed) Primary Keys of the tables ?(none of them has a UNIQUE constraint or index) What is their relation?

Comment: @wildplasser The problem is not contraint or relation between tables, the problem is that why the query behaves differently in function.

Comment: I think the indexes of the table are not used in the dynamic query. I don't know why.